# Efficient solution for a quadratic + norm objective.

Tags: convex-optimization

I want to minimize an objective function of the following form:
$$
\begin{split}
    \text{Minimize} \quad & x^T D_x x + y^T D_y y + z^T D_z z + 
                            q_x^T x + q_y^T y + q_z^T z + 
                            \lambda \cdot \begin{Vmatrix} y - x \\ z - x \end{Vmatrix}_2
\end{split}
$$

where $x, y, z \in R^n, \lambda > 0$ and $D \in R^{3n}$ is a positive-definite *diagonal* matrix. In addition, $n$ is "small" - less than 20.

I want to be able to solve it as efficiently as possible. I believe that there is a way to construct a dual that is a simple 1-D optimization problem over an interval that is quickly solvable, but I was not able to do so.

Comment: This problem has a trivial dual. To get the dual that you want, I think you need to move the norm into a constraint by adding a new variable $\|(y-z,z-x)\|_2\leq w$.

Comment: Well, that's why I said "a dual" and not "the dual". There is a trick I am missing here.
Using the idea you suggest, creating the dual is as hard as solving the original problem. Just look at the Lagrangian. That's why I believe that this does not lead to a useful dual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the generic problem
$$\inf_x \tfrac{1}{2}x^TPx+q^Tx+\lambda\|Rx\|_2$$
We can use a little trick to quickly get a dual without going through the full Lagrangian motions: since $\|w\|_2=\sum_{\|v\|_2\leq 1}v^Tw$, we have
$$\inf_x \sup_{\|w\|_2\leq 1} \tfrac{1}{2}x^TPx+q^Tx+w^TRx$$
Throwing caution to the wind (hey this isn't a journal article) we swap the $\inf$ and the $\sup$:
$$\sup_{\|w\|_2\leq 1} \inf_x \tfrac{1}{2}x^TPx+q^Tx+w^TRx$$
Since $P$ is positive definite the inner problem has a unique minimizer:
$$Px+q+R^Tw=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x = -P^{-1}(R^Tw+q)$$
Substitution yields
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sup_{\|w\|_2\leq 1} -\tfrac{1}{2}(R^Tw+q)^TP^{-1}(R^Tw+q)=
-\inf_{\|w\|_2\leq 1} \tfrac{1}{2}\|P^{-1/2}(R^Tw+q)\|_2^2 \\&\qquad=
-\inf_{\|w\|_2\leq 1} \tfrac{1}{2}w^TRP^{-1}R^Tw+q^TP^{-1}R^Tw+\tfrac{1}{2}q^TP^{-1}q
\end{aligned}$$

This is easier to solve than the original problem, for sure.

In fact, it's the well-known *trust region subproblem*. Here's what we know about it. First, try computing the unconstrained minimizer $w=(RP^{-1}R^T)^{-1}RP^{-1}q$. If it happens to satisfy $\|w\|_2\leq 1$, you're done: that's your constrained optimum. Otherwise, we know that the solution $w$ is a solution of the problem
$$\inf_w \|P^{-1/2}(R^Tw+q)\|_2^2+\bar{\lambda}\|w\|_2^2$$
where $\bar{\lambda}\geq 0$ is chosen so that $\|w\|_2=1$. For fixed $\bar{\lambda}$, the solution to this problem is just $(RP^{-1}R^T+\bar{\lambda}I)^{-1}RP^{-1}q$. You can use bisection to find the value of $\bar{\lambda}$.

If you're willing to compute the eigenvalue decomposition of $R^TP^{-1}R$ (or the SVD of $P^{-1/2}R$), you can solve it in $O(n)$ operations after that, I believe. But I don't know if you can readily exploit the structure of $P$ and $R$ here to speed up that SVD.

Comment: What a coincidence. After talking to some people, we have come to the same solution. Thanks :)